# Can I validate model calculated results in django.models or rest_framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-validation

Can I validate model calculated results in django.models or rest_framework?
e.g.

```py
class PointChange(models.Model):
        point_last_kpi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=False)
        point_last_non_kpi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, 
              null=False)
        point_last = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, 
               null=False)
```

I want to create a validation for 'point_last' as a value of 'point_last_non_kpi' + 'point_last_kpi'.
How to do that using django or django-rest-framework? Or validate it in views?

Comment: Where/when do you want this validation? pre-save? post-save? on querying?

Answer (score 0):

One way of making sure that point_last is the sum of point_last_kpi and point_last_non_kpi is that you can use pre_save from django models, with the help of pre_save, you can save the value of point_last as the sum of point_last_kpi and point_last_non_kpi, you'll have to take the values of point_last_kpi and point_last_non_kpi and **not point_last**, you can still change the value of point_last if you specifically give it some value from django admin or in some request from api.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

def default_point_last(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.point_last:
        instance.point_last = instance.point_last_kpi + instance.point_last_non_kpi


pre_save.connect(default_point_last, sender=PointChange)
```